# Mongodb query with PHP variable is not working with Limit

Tags: php, mongodb, limit

I have write a script for Mongodb with php and its working fine when limit is in static number while when we pass varible in script it throw error.

Script code is:

```
array(
                                "\$match" => array(
                                    "\$or" => array(
                                        array(
                                            'title' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex($queryString),
                                        ),
                                        array(
                                            'description' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex($queryString),
                                        ),
                                        array(
                                            'master.title' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex($queryString),
                                        ),
                                    ),

                                    "\$and" => array(
                                    array(
                                        'created_on' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex($filterDate)
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            ),

                            array(
                                '$sort' => array(
                                    'created_on' => -1
                                )
                            ),
                            array(
                                '$limit' => $filterLimit,
                            )
```

'$limit' => $filterLimit,  is not working while when we pass static number its working fine.

if we replace

```
                              array(
                                    '$limit' => $filterLimit,
                                )
```

to

```
                             array(
                                    '$limit' => 10,
                                )
```

its working fine.Below is the error

**Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\CommandException: the limit must be specified as a number in**

Comment: So what's the value of $filterLimit when you print it out?

Comment: Can you show where you are populating the value of $filterLimit ?

Comment: @MilanG,it is 20 but it may be any number

Comment: @John.M,it is in else if condition,I have print out and value is coming proper in number

Comment: it's clearly not or you wouldn't be getting that error. something is amiss in the way you are setting the value.

Comment: @John.M ,value is not missing and coming properly ,I have checked it many times

Comment: maybe there's whitespace being added or something that you aren't seeing

Comment: @John.M,I am using $filterLimit = trim($filterLimit); and value is coming in number format

Comment: @John.M,will this work in aggregate function ,$results = $collection->aggregate($ops);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$filterLimit` may be a string, try to cast it as an integer :

```
array(
    '$limit' => intval($filterLimit),
)
```